# Splitting UiImageView in half horizontally?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, split, uiimage, declare

How would I go about splitting a `UIImageView` In half horizontally? I don't want two separate images, but more just to declare two halves of the `UiImageView`. My final purpose is so that if my "ball" hits the top of a platform (top half) it bounces up. If the ball hits the bottom half of the platform, it bounces down.

Comment: could u elaborate? like, whats your final purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)split
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.jpeg"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    CGImageRef leftRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/2, image.size.height));
    UIImage *leftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:leftRef];
    CGImageRelease(leftRef);

    _imageView1.image = leftImage;

    CGImageRef rightRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(image.size.width /2, 0,  image.size.width , image.size.height));
    UIImage *rightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rightRef];
    CGImageRelease(rightRef);

    _imageView2.image = rightImage;
}
```